# Howto install latest SVNKit snapshot in Zend Studio 8 with jar file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, zend-studio, svnkit

In order to get support for Subversion 1.7 format files, I'm supposed to install an snapshot version of SVNKit 1.7 as says [here](http://svnkit.com/download.php). So I downloaded the jar file from [here](http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/snapshots/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/) but I don't know how to install it in Zend Studio 8, I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Update Site Archive can be found [here](http://www.svnkit.com/org.tmatesoft.svn_1.7.0-alpha1.eclipse.zip).